# Has the security of PuTTY been examined?

Tags: cryptography, windows, ssh

I am wondering how [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) stacks up against other SSH implementations with respect to scrutiny and security of its SSH2 protocol implementation.

PuTTY is probably the most-used SSH client on the Windows platform, so its importance cannot be understated.

I am aware that there have been several very crafty attacks in past years against SSL/TLS implementations (and, also, against the protocols themselves, but that is another issue).

In that light, I wonder if anyone has done work to validate/break SSH clients on the Windows platform and whether PuTTY fares well.

Comment: Resisting the need to point out that if you're using Windows then security must not be one of your core concerns. *Must...not..state...the...obvious..*

Answer (score 5):

Putty being open-source, there have been a number of *informal* security audits, some resulting in vulnerability reports and patches.

There may have also been some *formal* security audits commissioned by users of the product. Some searching revealed a bit of unverifiable evidence of such, but most importantly:

Simon doesn't advertise or reference any official audit of his code. Any audits done were done by a private party, for a private party, and may not have been scoped in such a way as to be applicable to your circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** My answer does not apply anymore. PuTTY is now served via  TLS with the GPG signatures hosted on the same site. Thanks to the PuTTY team for that!

---

Note that form what I've seen the official source for PuTTY is [http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) by the author and maintainer Simon Tatham.

Sadly this page is not available over TLS and the GPG signatures for the binaries link to an external page, so there is a serious risk of somebody tampering with your connection when you download putty potentially inserting malicious code or even redirecting to a different page for the signatures.

I've wanted to vent about this situation for a long time when I stumbled upon this question, a high-profile security critical software like PuTTY really shouldn't be distributed over plain HTTP.

Comment: Seems to have https now. It's using an acme cert.